# Shortest Solution in Python 3 for Caught Speeding - CodingBat

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I am trying to find the shortest code in **python 3**, to solve this problem:

You are driving a little too fast, and a police officer stops you.

Write code to take two integer inputs, first one corresponds to speed, seconds one is either 1 or 0, corresponding to True and False respectively to indicate whether it is birthday. Then compute the result, encoded as an int value:

0=no ticket,

1=small ticket,

2=big ticket.

If speed is 60 or less, the result is 0. If speed is between 61 and 80 inclusive, the result is 1. If speed is 81 or more, the result is 2. Unless it is your birthday -- on that day, your speed can be 5 higher in all cases.

```
input:
60
0
Output:
0

input:
65
0
Output:
1

input:
65
1
output:
0
```

Here's my shortest solution (`57 chars`). Is there any way I can make it shorter in Python?

```
print(min(2,max(0,(int(input())-5*int(input())-41)//20)))
```

Reference: *Problem inspired from [this](https://codingbat.com/prob/p137202)*

Comment: @JoKing I did not know, I will add `tips` tag. Not sure if I want this to become a competition. If you recommend I can add `code-golf` as well.

Comment: What's the range of possible speeds? I think this can have a big effect on what shortcuts are possible.

Comment: It would be @xnor 0 to 199

Comment: Does it have to be in Python 3, or is Python 2 fine as well? I think Python 2 could save quite a number of bytes.

Comment: Python 3. Will add this in the question/tags.

Comment: @xnor but I will be interested if there's anything other than `input` that can save bytes in python 2.

Comment: Other than `input` and `print` without parens, Python 2 has `cmp`, which should let you do your method without the `min/max` clamping.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 32 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(a-b*5>60)+(a-b*5>80)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIVEnyUojUTdJy9TOzEBTG8q0MND8X1CUmVeikaYBIjPzCkpLNDQ1dRSQeZqa/81MuQwA)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>50</s></sup> 49 bytes

If io must be done with stdin and stdout

```python
a,b=map(int,open(0));print((a-b*5>60)+(a-b*5>80))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1EnyTY3sUAjM69EJ78gNU/DQFPTuqAIyNXQSNRN0jK1MzPQ1IYyLYCS//9bGHIZAAA)

-1 byte thanks to [@dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)

Comment: Ah! Beautiful! Thanks! Would accept in a while.

Comment: Save some characters by doing `i=input;` (-3) and then later `i()` (+8) for a total of +5 characters saved.

Comment: Do you mean like `i=input;s=int(i())-5*int(i());print((s>60)+(s>80))`?

Comment: @LMD could you show what you did? I tried this yesterday, couldn't shrink below 50 bytes.

Comment: @SayandipDutta, yeah, like Mukundan showed

Comment: @LMD The code I showed still uses 50 bytes

Comment: @Mukundan yeah, my fault

Comment: Late comment, but `a,b=map(int,open(0))` would be just one byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>51</s> 45 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:min(2,max(0,(a//1-5*b//1-41)//20))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqNzNPw0gnN7FCw0BHI1Ff31DXVCsJRJkYaurrGxloav4vKMrMK9FI0zAz0FEA8rngfFNMviFQPQA)

I was able to shave 6 bytes from your approach by using everyone's favourite python golfing keyword: `lambda`.

This turns your program into an anonymous function, which then can be called in the footer of a program.

Edit: I know that this question is way old, but I only just recently thought of using `//1` to convert things to an integer instead of using `int(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. But need to take input, and print as well. Meant to be a script, can't eval on repl :\

Comment: @SayandipDutta Functions are usually considered valid responses here

Comment: I'm sure they are. It's just that it didn't suit my usecase. I hope you understand :)